# Display the name of the site manager in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display the username of the main site administrator for a part of my template.

I have used the following short code to display the email address of the main administrator of the site with which he started WordPress:

```
<?php bloginfo('admin_email'); ?>
```

But I did not find any short code to display the username of the main administrator of the site.

Is there such a **shortcode** or should I get the username of the main administrator of the site in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get the user for the email that the admin set during setup you can do so by combining `bloginfo('admin_email')` and `get_user_by()` functions.

Something similar to:

```php
$username = 'Unknown'; // Default name in case WP_User could not be found.
$admin_email = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
$admin_user = get_user_by( 'email', $admin_email );
if ($admin_user) {
  $username = $admin_user->get('user_login');
}
echo $username;
```

Take into account that once you get the WP_User object ($admin_user) you can retrieve any value from the `wp_users` table (see [here)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users).

Comment: Hello. I got the email just looking to get the admin username. Please, if it's possible, give me a piece of code so that I can easily get only the username of the person who started WordPress (the main administrator).

Comment: @user21540512 Didn't I do that? Have you tried the code?

Comment: Your code only gives me the administrator's email, which I don't need, and I'm only looking for the site administrator's username. In addition, using your code, I also received this error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function get_user_by()`

Comment: Meanwhile, I am testing on **localhost**.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, updated the code. I messed up the call to `get_user_by`. Anyway I saw you already have an accepted answer. Happy you got it working :)

Comment: Again, it gives me the email and the word (**Unknown**) instead of the username.
I don't want to show the email, just the **username** is enough for me. The WordPress shortcode that I have included in my question displays the administrator's email, but I am looking for a code to display the administrator's **username**.

Comment: Oops again, I was using `bloginfo` (which prints the email) instead of `get_bloginfo`. Now it should work. But if you are seeing "Unknown" it means that there is no user with the email set for the admin email. As other have told you there is no concept as "main administrator". So if the site admin email is not the same as the admin you want... There isn't much you can do. However you can get the list of all the admins or the current logged in user. Maybe if you give more information on what you are trying to do we can help better?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a shortcode that I know of, but writing one is very simple, and a great exercise to learn shortcode creation:

```
function admin_email_shortcode() { 
 return bloginfo('admin_email');
}

add_shortcode('admin_email', 'admin_email_shortcode');
```

Simply add that code to your themes functions.php file and use the shortcode `[admin_email]` where you want the email address to be displayed.

As a bonus, here's another shortcode for you that would generate a list of all site Admins if there was more than one:

```
function admin_emails_shortcode() { 
 $admins = get_users('role=Administrator');
 foreach ($admins as $admin) {
  $adminList .= $admin->user_email.", ";
 }  
  return rtrim($adminList, ', ');
 }

add_shortcode('admin_emails', 'admin_emails_shortcode');
```

To get the FIRST administrators email address:

```
function first_administrator_email() { 
 $adminsArray = array();
 $admins = get_users('role=Adviser'); //Administrator
 foreach ($admins as $admin) {
  $adminsArray[$admin->id] = $admin->user_email;
 }  
 
 return $adminsArray[min(array_keys($adminsArray))];
}

add_shortcode('first_admin_email', 'first_administrator_email');
```

Comment: Hello. I got the email. I am looking to get the username of the main administrator of the site.

Comment: This code does that,  but what do you mean by "main" administrator?

Comment: I mean the person who started WordPress, not the people who were promoted to the management level.

Comment: In Wordpress all users with user level Administrator are treated the same. I suppose the only way to tell them apart would be to retrieve the lowest ID.... one moment.

Comment: I put your code as `<?php admin_emails_shortcode(); ?>` but I got this error: `Warning: Undefined variable $adminList in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\wp-content\themes\AForushShop\functions.php on line 362`

Comment: That is not correct. You either use the shortcode in the editor ```[admin_email]``` or invoke the shortcode in PHP with ```<?php echo do_shortcode( '[admin_email]' ); ?>```

Comment: You weren't the downvote right?

Comment: Yes. I am not allowed to vote.

Comment: Dear friend, your code only gives me the site administrator's email, which I don't need. I am looking for the username of the site administrator. I use the shortcode: `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[first_admin_email]' ); ?>` but I got the following error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: min(): Argument #1 ($value) must contain at least one element in ...`

Comment: Mate these are simple mods. Change ```user_email``` to ```user_login``` would appreciate an upvote, so far lost rep after doing 20 minutes work haha

Comment: I just want the code that gives me the **username** of the **main administrator** of the site.

Comment: Understand there is no such thing as "main administrator" all administrators are the same, but I have supplied working, adn tested code to retrieve the admin with the lowest user ID (ie the first admin) which I think is safe to assume is your "main" admin

Comment: Thankful. I realized. I can't vote but I accept your answer. Thank you for your time.